# Equivalence relation notation

Tags: notation, equivalence-relations

Suppose that we want to define an equivalence relation $\sim$ on some space $X$ by $x_1 \sim x_2$ if $x_1 = -x_2$. Is it correct to just define $\sim$ by just saying $x_1 \sim -x_2$?

Comment: Your relation may not be an equivalence relation because it will be reflexive only if every element is  additive inverse of itself. So you definitely need to say something else.

Comment: Typically when an equivalence relation is given, only the relation between elements other than itself are given since things such as reflexivity and symmetry are boring and assumed. I'm not even ensuring transitivity. We can always extend it to an equivalence relation, but that's not the point of the question.

Comment: Ok, Then you can just say that you are taking an equivalence closure of $x_2 \sim -x_2 $.

Comment: Searching didn't help too much, but what is an "equivalence closure"? Moreover, what is an equivalence closure of $x_2 \sim -x_2$?

Comment: Generally one writes

$$x\sim y\iff P(x,y)$$

where $P(x,y)$ is the condition to be equivalent.

Comment: @Masacroso Got that (as seen in the question where I say "$x_1 \sim x_2$ if $x_1 = -x_2$"), but I'm asking if the "lazier" way of saying it is also correct.

Comment: @Irregular Equivalence closure of relation $R$ is the smallest equivalence relation containing $R$, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(mathematics)

Comment: @IrregularUser the "lazy" way is correct if you first define this non standard notation. What you propose is some kind of abuse of notation, but not too dangerous IMO.

Comment: @Masacroso Good to know that it's non-standard, which actually answers the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. If the relation $\sim$ is defined by $x_1 \sim x_2$ when $x_1 = -x_2$, then all you can say is $x_1\sim x_2$.

Because to say $x_1 \sim -x_2$ means $x_1 = -(-x_2)$, which is  $x_1 = x_2$